# Know of any Firebird profilers and/or stress tester app's?

Tags: testing, profiling, firebird, stress-testing, sql-server-profiler

I'm looking for som testing programs for a firebird db server, to stress-test and find bottlenecks.

Something like [DB-Optimizer](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/db-optimizer-xe/), only for firebird would be nice. 
Can also be separate programs, one for stress-testing and one for profiling.

Answer (score 2):

You may look :

- [sinatica](http://www.sinatica.com) monitor
- [IBSurgeon](http://www.ibsurgeon.com) tools
- [IBExpert](http://www.ibExpert.com)

and you can also just request [monitoring tables](http://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb210-mon) (Firebird 2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing Hugues answer:

Sinatica monitor uses monitoring tables from Firebird 2.1, so will not work very well on FB2.0 or below.

IBExpert have his own type of monitoring tables to help you in this task.

If you are using FB 2.5 you can look also [Firebird Trace Manager](http://www.upscene.com/products.misc.fbtm.php).

To make some stress tests using your own application you can always look for AutoHotkey. Just be careful... Sometimes you can really mess things with it.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter may work rather well, as it's fairly easy to setup a basic DB request test, and can be incredibly flexible.

- [Overview](http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html)
- [Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [Firebird profiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fbprofiler/) to trace the queries